# Can't generate font from AIGA symbolset

Tags: fonts, svg, symbols, file-conversion, eps

I'm collecting different public-domain [pictograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictogram) for a project of mine. I download some symbolset, possibly transform it from `EPS` to `SVG` using [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), and generate a font from them using [SVG-icon-font-generator](https://github.com/madeyourday/SVG-Icon-Font-Generator). This procedure led to satisfactory results until I stumbled upon [AIGA pedestrian symbols](http://www.aiga.org/symbol-signs/).

After conversion to `SVG` format, I'm unable to generate font from them, the icon generator throws the following exception:

> [Exception]
>   01_telephone-xe001.svg: Transforms are currently not supported!

I tried converting the files using [pstoedit](http://www.pstoedit.net/), but that didn't help. I tried to search for these symbols elsewhere, so I managed to find them as a part of linux `openclipart` package as SVG files but the same error occured.

My question is: How to remove the non-supported transformations from SVG files in order to succesfully generate font from them? Or, does anyone know where to download them without that transformation?

**UPDATE**

I have opened the file in [svg-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html). Then I saved it and compared to the original. It turns out that the data in the original svg file had a leading `xml` tag declaration. The svg-editor removed the `xml` tag and all of the custom tag attributes (`xmnls:something`, `inkscape:something`).

The font generation still failed. The picture was grouped as stated in Duopixel's answer, so I've ungrouped it and saved. That removed `g` tags with `transform`  attributes. After that, the font was generated successfully.

Here is the comparison, open the image in a new tab to see it bigger:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the SVG in SVG-Edit http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html. If the SVG is grouped then ungroup it. Select each path and if the path has a transformation, then this button will be enabled:

[image]

This is the "reorient path tool" it applies the transformation to a path, which is most likely what you need. If this doesn't work, then upload your SVG file somewhere where we can take a look at the code.

Comment: I apologize for late feedback. The tool is really neat! :)